# Как узнать какой игрок покинул комнату в OnPlayerLeftRoom, Photon?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Изучаю Photon. Хочу, чтобы при выходе игрока из комнаты, его спрайт для оставшихся игроков заменялся. Замену спрайта реализовал в функции `Kill()`.
В функции OnPlayerLeftRoom написал такой код:

```
public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
{
    // Когда другой игрок покинул комнату
    PlayerController player = Map.Players.First(p => p.photonView.Owner == null);
    player.Kill();
}
```

Узнал из видео, что когда игрок выходит из комнаты, его `Owner` устанавливается на null. Однако этот код не работает: выдается ошибка о том, что подобного элемента в массиве не найдено. И правда, я смотрю в инспекторе, а объект игрока, вышедшего из комнаты, теперь принадлежит ***мастер-клиенту!***

Вопрос: как найти в массиве компонентов `PlayerController` того игрока, который вышел из комнаты? Почему при выходе игрока из комнаты (функцией `PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom()`) его `Owner` - это не сцена, не null, а мастер-клиент? В итоге у меня объект вышедшего игрока начинает повторять движения игрока мастер-клиента.

P.S. Свойство photonView в скрипте игрока — это ссылка на компонент PhotonView, висящий на игроке.

Comment: Вот здесь есть подробная информация: https://doc.photonengine.com/zh-cn/pun/current/gameplay/ownershipandcontrol

Comment: На сколько я понял, для желаемого поведения нужно установить параметр `PlayerTtl` (время жизни неактивного игрока) в 0 при создании комнаты
(см. `RoomOption`), но не уверен на 100%

Comment: PS: но я бы скорее искал по совпадению `otherPlayer.ActorNumber` и `p.photonView.CreatorActorNr` или что-то вроде этого

Comment: @SergeySkvortsov Вариант с PlayerTtl не прокатил, на что бы я не устанавливал, а вот предложенная вами проверка сработала. Это не совсем ответ на вопрос, но так как это решило проблему, то я приму ваш ответ, если вы его напишите.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь создать в классе PlayerController поле c называнием NickName или что-то другое и потом проверить по нему.
К примеру:
PlayerController player = Map.Players.First(p => p.NickName.Contains(otherPlayer.NickName));